# No route matches but created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I have spent a lot of time but I don't know how to solve this problem.

I need to send PUT request and I want to do it with ajax by click on checkbox

My HAML

```
- subcate.products.each do |product|
  = check_box_tag 'published', product.id, product.published, id: '',                             |
    data: {                                                                                       |
      remote: true,                                                                               |
      url: url_for(controller 'products', action: :set_published, id: product.id, method: 'PUT'), |

    }
```

My routes

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :categories
    resources :subcategories
    resources :posts

    resources :products do
      resources :images, only: [:create, :destroy]
      put 'set_published', to: 'products#set_published'
    end
  end
```

My controller

```
class Admin::ProductsController < AdminController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def set_published
    "test"
  end

end
```

When I type

```
rake routes
```

I got

```
  admin_product_set_published     PUT     /admin/products/:product_id/set_published(.:format)        admin/products#set_published
```

My checkbox is on the main admin page and when i want to enter I got

```
No route matches {:action=>"set_published", :controller=>"admin/products", :id=>49, :method=>"PUT"}
```

But i try to test controller from console

```
Admin::ProductsController.new.set_published
```

i got

```
=> "test"
```

I don't know what is wrong with the routes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bzuY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake routes` tells you that it expects a `product_id`:

```
/admin/products/:product_id/set_published(.:format)
```

But in `url_for` you provide a `id`:

```
url_for(controller 'products', action: :set_published, id: product.id, method: 'PUT')
```

Just change it to (and I recommend using the path method):

```
admin_product_set_published_path(product_id: product.id)
```